# The method is not displaying the result in OOP in PHP

Tags: php, oop

i am practicing oop in php. and im quite new to oop in php. im trying to work the following code but its not working properly. The thing is the displayCalculation method is not printing the value of variables. But the calculateHours method is working and displaying output, i have tested it. What i am doing wrong. Please give an answer according to the below syntax, i know i can perform this in many other ways, but i want to know whats wrong in this one. Thankyou for your time.

```
<?php

class Calculate {
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $night_hours;

    public function calculateHours($u_age, $u_name, $u_hours) {
        $this->age = $u_age;
        $this->name = $u_name;
        $this->night_hours = $u_hours;
        $calc = ($this->age * $this->night_hours) / 24;
        return $calc;
    }
    public function displayCalculation() {
        $this->calculateHours($this->age, $this->name, $this->night_hours);
        echo "Mr." . $this->name . " you have wasted " . $calc . " years of your life sleepin..";
    }
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>OOP Form</title>
    <style>
    body{background-color:black;color:white;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <center>Calculate Slept Years</center>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="form1">
        Enter Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="u_name" placeholder="Enter Name"><br>
        Age:<br>
        <input type="text" name="u_age" placeholder="Enter Age"><br>
        Night Sleep Hours:<br>
        <input type="text" name="u_hours" placeholder="Enter Hours you Sleep at night"><br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Calculate">
    </form>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["btn"])) {
        $u_age = $_POST["u_age"];
        $u_name = $_POST["u_name"];
        $u_hours = $_POST["u_hours"];

        $calculate = new Calculate($u_age, $u_name, $u_hours);
        $calculate->displayCalculation();
        echo $calculate->calculateHours($u_age, $u_name, $u_hours);
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good formatting is *incredibly* important and worth practising too

Comment: @SmallLegend..yeah....im doing it in Calculatehours function..look closely..the $this->name refers to $name and so on..

Comment: Yeah I saw it and deleted my comment haha, thanks man @mastermind

Comment: hahaha clever...no problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here are the problem I can see:

1. You call a constructor method, but there isn't one (not a problem, just pointless) - `$calculate = new Calculate($u_age, $u_name, $u_hours);`
2. You call `displayCalculation()` before you calculate it. This is probably confusion surrounding the constructor issue above.
3. Your `displayCalculation()` method calls `$calc` which isn't defined. It should be the return value of `$this->calculateHours()`

I think you're just a bit confused about how this code is being instantiated and run. Here are my suggestions:

Add a constructor method which will set your variables (add validation later):

```
class Calculate {
    ...
    public function __construct($u_age, $u_name, $u_hours) {
        $this->age = $u_age;
        $this->name = $u_name;
        $this->night_hours = $u_hours;
    }
}
```

Now, instantiate `Calculate` and pass in your variables:

```
$calculate = new Calculate($u_age, $u_name, $u_hours);
```

Finally, call the `displayCalculation()` method from your HTML. Leave the actual calculation calls etc to the `Calculate` class to handle itself:

```
$calculate->displayCalculation();
```

You will need to adjust your `displayCalculation()` method to use the return value from the `calculateHours()` method. The idea of OOP in this particular example is that the constructor sets the variables when the `Calculate` class is instantiated, so you don't need to pass the variables around inside the class. Instead, just access them via `$this->age` etc from any method:

```
protected function calculateHours() {
    $calc = ($this->age * $this->night_hours) / 24;
    return $calc;
}
```

Note that I've made that method protected instead of public, which means you can't call it from outside the class (i.e. from the HTML). You should only want to call the `displayCalculation()` method, so only that one (and the constructor) will be public.

Of course, you may actually disagree with me here and say "what if I want to access the calculation data without the formatting?" - in that case, sure - make it public again.

So your class would end up like this:

```
class Calculate {
    protected $name;
    protected $age;
    protected $night_hours;

    public function __construct($u_age, $u_name, $u_hours) {
        $this->age = $u_age;
        $this->name = $u_name;
        $this->night_hours = $u_hours;
    }

    protected function calculateHours() {
        $calc = ($this->age * $this->night_hours) / 24;
        return $calc;
    }

    public function displayCalculation() {
        $calc = $this->calculateHours();
        echo "Mr." . $this->name . " you have wasted " . $calc . " years of your life sleepin..";
    }
}
```

And your HTML:

```
if (isset($_POST["btn"])) {
    $u_age = $_POST["u_age"];
    $u_name = $_POST["u_name"];
    $u_hours = $_POST["u_hours"];

    $calculate = new Calculate($u_age, $u_name, $u_hours);
    $calculate->displayCalculation();
}
```

**Edit:** just noticed that your class properties are all public too - this means you could actually set them all from outside the class i.e. in the HTML. I don't really like this approach, so in the examples above I've changed them to protected instead and you will set them from the constructor arguments.

Comment: and one more question though.. if im using the __construct class in the above example like you have stated. there is no need to first call the calculate method before displayCalculation???

Comment: Not in that example, the calculation method gets called when you call `displayCalculation()` - the class handles that. I think a good way to think about it is in modules, i.e. the frontend and the backend. What does the frontend want? It wants to provide a bunch of values, and then ask for the calculation. It shouldn't need to tell the backend that the calculation needs to be performed, that would is implied by the fact that the FE asks the BE for the calculation to be displayed